# Runge-Kutta Approach to Relativistic Kepler Problem

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, computational-physics, estimation

I am attempting to solve the relativistic Kepler problem using fourth order Runge-Kutta, however I am having trouble and am unsure why I simply cannot get the correct orbits no matter how I adjust the initial values. My orbits are not even incorrect but they are nonsensical, I was wondering if there are issues with the Runge-Kutta algorithm when solving such problems? The geodesic equations in Schwarzschild spacetime (in geometric units) are:

\begin{align}
&\frac{d^2r}{d\tau^2} = \frac{M}{r(r - 2M)} \left(\frac{dr}{d\tau}\right)^2-\frac{M(r - 2M)}{r^3} \left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right)^2 + (r - 2M) \left(\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}\right)^2
\\[0.5em]
&\frac{d^2t}{d\tau^2} = - \frac{2M}{r(r - 2M)} \frac{dr}{d\tau} \frac{dt}{d\tau}
\\[0.5em]
&\frac{d^2\phi}{d\tau^2} = - \frac{2}{r} \frac{dr}{d\tau} \frac{d\phi}{d\tau}
\end{align}

We can convert the above to a system of 6 1st order ODE's by setting:
\begin{align}
y_1 = r \\[0.5em]
y_2 = \frac{dr}{d\tau} \\[0.5em]
y_3 = \phi \\[0.5em]
y_4 = \frac{d\phi}{d\tau} \\[0.5em]
y_5 = t \\[0.5em]
y_6 = \frac{dt}{d\tau}
\end{align}

So then, we obtain 6 1st order ODEs which can be solved using the fourth order Runge - Kutta. For example, I tested my code on mercury with the following parameters (geometrized units):
\begin{align}
&\text{Mass of sun: } 1474 m \\[0.5em]
&\text{Mecury radius at perihelion: } 46.002\times 10^9 m
\end{align}

I am not sure about the initial values for the Runge Kutta so I tried a range such as
$$
[y_1(0), y_2(0), y_3(0), y_4(0), y_5(0), y_6(0)] = [46.002\times 10^9, 0, 0, 1\times 10^{-16}, 0, 1]
$$
Despite the range of initial values i have tried, I cannot seem to get even a decent orbit.

Is there a problem with using Runge-Kutta to solve these equations or should there be a more deterministic way to obtain the initial values?

Comment: You use nondimensional form of the dynamic equation system and try to use dimensional  initial condition. This is first typo. The second one is that you not define orbital   velocity of Mercury.

Comment: ... and when you have fixed the problems Alex Trounev mentioned, you will then hit the problem that the Runge-Kutta method does not conserve energy, so even with classical mechanics you will not get closed orbits.

Comment: Whilst @alephzero is 100% correct about energy conservation, this is still a very interesting problem to solve.  When you have something working as far as RK4 can in this situation, you might be motivated to look at _symplectic integrators_ (which _do_ conserve energy for certain classes of problem), but also the (4 dimensional rather than 8) "velocity equations" for the Kerr metric which is in MTW and also a seminal paper by Wilkins ("Bound geodesics in the Kerr metric", 1972).  Using all this I eventually came up with an efficient method, but it was a challenge!

Comment: @m4r35n357 Note that those equations first appeared in Carter's 1968 paper "Global Structure of the Kerr Family of Gravitational Fields".

Comment: @mmeent I believe you, but as a non-academic I can't see for myself;  Wilkins' paper is available as a PDF on the open internet, which is how I found it, and why I use it as a reference.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Hi! Apologies, I do not really understand what you mean by "dimensional initial conditions", does that mean the initial conditions containing meters is incorrect? If so, what would be the correct initial conditions? Also regarding the orbital velocity, it is the tangential velocity right? But that term is not present in my equations?

Comment: @alephzero Thank you! Would choosing a smaller step size help to resolve the problem?

Comment: @m4r35n357 Thank you! I will read up about symplectic integrators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this model with RK method of order 8 to understand how it depends on input error and step size as well. First we should note, that relativistic model has hidden suggestion in the form $c=1$ where c is the speed of light. In this case the unit of time and coordinate is the same, for instance, meter. Second, we take Mercury semimajor axis, perihelion, eccentricity, period  in days and maximal orbital speed as

```
Mmercury = 3.3010 10^23; RAmercury = 5.7909227 10^10; RPmercury = 4.6002 10^10; Emercury = 0.20563593; Pmercury = 87.97; vp=58983;
```

We use Mercury perihelion as a scale of length, therefore in this case we have parameter M of the model and initial condition as follows

```
c0 = 299792458.; GM = 1.32712 10^(20); mS = GM/c0^2; M=mS/RPmercury ;
```

$$t(0)= 0, r(0) = 1, \phi(0) = 0, t'(0) = u_1, 
   r'(0) = 0, \phi'(0)= vp/c0$$
Here `u1` is computed as a root of equation
$$u.g.u=-1, u=(u1,0,0,vp/c0)$$
g is the metric tensor. We have calculated, that $u1=1.0000000514518859$. Also we define time scale $t_0=RPmercury/c0=153.446 s$, hence in equations we should normalize $t$ on $t_0$. Finally we compute orbit as shown in Figure 1
[image: Figure 1]

According this calculation the period is about $49569*t0=7.60617*10^6$, while astronomical data says that period is about $Pmercury *24*3600=7.60061*10^6$. Therefore we have discrepancies in time period, but it is not due to relativistic dilation , but due to error in definition of input parameter and computation method.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you very much for your help, please give me awhile before i accept your answer as I would like to work out the details first. Also would you mind explaining your notation for 
$$ u.g.u = 0$$

Comment: Are you referring to $u \cdot u = -1?$

Comment: @D.Soul Thank you very much for this remarks. I have corrected this typo. Apparently it should be $u.g.u=-1$, as in the code on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189961/interpreting-mathematica-code-on-black-holes . If you interested in Hamilton's equation, then have a look on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190608/integrating-hamiltons-equations-for-the-schwarzschild-metric/190621#190621